# What's the red light in the left wing of a N.A. T-6 for?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-external-lights

There's a yearly flight show near my location, and there's always this North American T-6 (D-FUKK):
[image]

Today, I noticed that there's a single white light in the leading edge of the right wing, but a white and a red light in the left wing.

What's that red light for?

Comment: @mins and there is, but he's asking about the one on the leading edge ;)

Comment: lol that airport code

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's the **passing light.** They're no longer in use.

In an era of virtually zero radar air traffic control, two planes headed for each other at high speed at night needed those [very bright] lights. They would use the right-of-way rule to stay on the 'right lane' and safely *pass* each other.

[image]
([jetphotos.com](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/6637135)) Clearer view for D-FUKK.

---

[image]
([Code of Federal Regulations](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cun17RA3fxIC)) Points (a) and (c) match the T-6.

> a strong red light to warn passing airplanes displayed usually in the leading edge on an airplane flying after dark ([merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passing%20light)).

[image]
([Source](http://aircraft-in-focus.com/wp-content/gallery/connie-pimatwa/scan-130331-0008.jpg)) Early [Connie's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Constellation) had them in the nose (b).

Comment: heh... passing light. I can see the T-6 flashing its light at the Connie to get it to move out of the left lane... :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this is different from the red/green position lights.

Comment: @zymhan: It's "strong", and based on the images, it's directional, as [opposed to this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/65398/14897). So, when they saw that bright red ahead, they kept it to the left.