# Do airplanes or helicopters ever fly at night using only white navigation lights?

Tags: aircraft-identification, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, aircraft-external-lights

I've been trying to figure out if airplanes or helicopters ever fly at night with only white Nav Lights.

See [this UAV video](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ugqvjlwzqvpu2p0/AAAAkcmM3Huy6xYmsXoCreXJa?dl=0) taken on July 12, 2015, 05:38 AM Pacific time in San Francisco, CA, USA.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! What exactly is your question? Because this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, we generally avoid opinions and prefer questions that can have a clear answer. The [tour] may be helpful if you're new to the site.

Comment: I'm so sorry!  I've been trying to figure out if airplanes or helicopters ever fly at night with *only* white Nav Lights. That's the crux of my inquiry and in the course of google searching to answer my Q, I fell upon this website.  Again, very sorry if this is the wrong forum.  I'll take a look at the "tour."

Comment: Welcome to the site. Best to edit the question, and include the information from the comment.

Comment: Shaky camera work, limited resolution, in the dark. I assume you're intending to focus on the flickering lights to right of centre, which could be anything. Whichever answer you get to your posted question ('yes' or 'no') I don't see how that will provide any useful information.

Comment: Related: [Placement of positioning lights on A320 winglets](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/65397/14897)

Answer (score 1):

There are no such things as white navigation lights - nav light, by definition, are red/green/white.

However, we're talking about filming lights at night. And the problem here is that the light source, no matter what colour, is a concentrated source of light in major contrast to the lack of light around it. And so the light will often 'burn in' on a camera and appear to be a lot of light, ie white, where the human eye will pick up the colours.