# What pattern of position lights did early Soviet jetliners use?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-lighting, soviet-union

All aircraft that operate at night or in poor weather need [position lights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_light#Aviation_navigation_lights) to make them visible to other aircraft for the purpose of avoiding mid-air collisions.  On most aircraft, these follow a set pattern: two continuously-illuminated lights on the wingtips (red on the left wingtip, green on the right [a pattern inherited from marine navigation lights], to allow other aircraft to see whether yours is flying towards or away from them), a continuously-illuminated white light in the tail, and high-intensity white anticollision strobe lights on each wingtip, in the tail, and on the upper and lower surfaces of the fuselage.

However, according to the Wikipedia article on the [Ilyushin Il-62](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-62), early Soviet jetliners did *not* follow the standard arrangement for position lighting:

> The Il-62 entered Aeroflot civilian service on 15 September 1967 with an inaugural passenger flight from Moscow to Montreal, and remained the standard long-range airliner for the Soviet Union (and later, Russia) for several decades. It was the first Soviet pressurised aircraft with non-circular cross-section fuselage and ergonomic passenger doors, and the first Soviet jet with six-abreast seating (the turboprop Tu-114 shared this arrangement) **and international-standard position lights.**  *[Emphasis added.]*

What arrangement of position lighting did pre-Il-62 Soviet jetliners use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was a tough one. The USSR joined ICAO in 1970.<sup>[a]</sup> The colors and positions would have been the same, since those carried over from maritime conventions.

What isn't the same, based on checking warbirds, is the viewing angle. The red/green lights in ICAO/Western standards are [not viewable from behind](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/65398/14897), but Soviet aircraft did not have that distinction. They also had separate top/bottom navigation lights, even the license-built DC-3 (Li-2) was modified to have that top/bottom arrangement.<sup>[1]</sup>

Judging by the Yak-40 (an early Soviet jetliner), they lacked the white wingtip lights<sup>[b]</sup> that are viewable from behind -- compare with the ICAO-compliant Il-62 *(shown on the right):*

> [image: russian soviet aircraft navigation position lights]
> Both aircraft are stored; sources: [scalemodels.ru](http://scalemodels.ru/modules/photo/viewcat_cid_544.html) and [elevation.maplogs.com](https://elevation.maplogs.com/poi/g_ttlin_rathenow_germany.559652.html)

For the aforementioned warbirds, below shows an American F4F *(annotated)* and a Soviet Il-2:

> [image: russian soviet aircraft navigation position lights]
> Sources: [primeportal.net](http://www.primeportal.net/hangar/sal_provenzano/f4f-3_wildcat/) and [primeportal.net](http://www.primeportal.net/hangar/bill_spidle5/il-2m3_305401/)

---

1: http://www.dc3history.org/airlinesoftheworld/russianaviation.html

a: I'm not sure whether Soviet transport aircraft that flew internationally and were built prior would have been retrofitted

b: technically those are anti-collision lights, but unfortunately the Wikipedia statement is vague and lacking in-line citation -- the ICAO-equivalent became effective in 1962 according to SARPs Annex 6 part 1

Comment: The Il-62 having international-standard lighting but _not_ the Yak-40 is weird, given that the Il-62 _predates_ the Yak-40!

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean: My bet it's because the -40 is regional/short-range.