# What was in the noses of airliners before the weather radar?

Tags: airliner, aviation-history, equipment, nose

At the time of the first Lockheed Constellations, airliners fitted with a weather radar were not common, and the navigator was not placed in the airplane nose. Thus, the nose seems to be mostly dead space.

Was the nose dead space with no useful equipment in it, or was it used for equipment I don't know about?

Comment: One data point here.  I have seen a DC3 with the nose opened up (hinged on top).  It had some electronics up there.  Not much, but it was basically an E&E bay.

Comment: Maybe a frog in a jar with a ladder?

Comment: Machine guns!!!

Comment: Older aircraft noses had a lot of hair.

Comment: @HotLicks I was thinking "bombardier"

Comment: Lights? Radio equipment? Plenty of other instrumentation to put there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]
([Source](http://aircraft-in-focus.com/lockheed-constellation/))

Externally, the Connie *(shown above)* had lights, with the red being the now obsolete [passing light](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/43450/14897).

From the high-res [DC-3](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/09/8e/3c/098e3cc0ada5f31f48e7da925cbe32a6.jpg) and [DC-7](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/10/af/19/10af190eb64ef6240eb1d5f0b5d3da0a.jpg) cutaways, all sort of stuff, from autopilot oil and air filters, wiring, windshield spray systems, to hydraulic reservoirs.

There wasn't one main object like there's now, nor was it completely empty. Its main aerodynamic function remains though.